# jQuery Ajax Doesn't POST on Safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asynchronous, post

I'm working on a project where a piece of the DOM is determined after a jQuery AJAX request. The code is working fine in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and even Edge. The issue comes with all (from what I can see) modern version of Safari.

It seems that the request isn't being completed on Safari at all - but it's not throwing any errors so the other JavaScript on the page (that doesn't involved POST/GET Requests) is working as intended. The console doesn't have any errors, either.

Here is a look at the code I'm using to make one of the requests:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/include/userbar.php',
      async: false,
   }).done(function(data){
      if(data.replace('Invalid Permissions') == data){
         $('#userBarContain').html(data);
      } else {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/include/guestbar.php',
            async: false
         }).done(function(data){
            $('#userBarContain').html(data);
         });
       }
});
```

Basically, we do an AJAX request on `$(document).ready()` and if the data returned is an `Invalid Permissions` error, we do the second request for the `guestbar.php`. Regarless of where we post to, we put the data returned into the `$('#userBarContain')` DOM element.

In Safari, I'm not seeing either the successful OR the fallback data being inserted into the DOM. I read that Safari doesn't always play well with `async` requests, but even with `async: false` I'm seeing the same issues.

**EDIT:** After getting access to a modern Macbook, I've found that it was actually a CSS3 selector I was using elsewhere that was causing this problem (without errors in the console unless I called the function again manually). I wanted to update this for future Google Searches that might come across this issue as well.

The selector in question was `$('*[name^="option["')`. Apparently, Safari doesn't play well with this sort of selector. After appending a class to the object(s) that I needed to iterate through, the problem seems to have been resolved.

Comment: Did you try to debug and see where the code stops working?

Comment: @Dekel I have tried debugging. The issue I'm running into is that the code just doesn't seem to be firing at all on Safari. Even a `console.log()` before we post doesn't show up in Safari.

Comment: @Ryan This is where the Network tab in Safari becomes helpful. You should be able to narrow down exactly what's happening in the request -- headers, content sent/received, etc. If you can provide us with details from that tab, that'll be helpful (Google for some usage guides). Everything looks right from your code, could be stumbling on a weird HTTP header or something.

Comment: @Ryan Oh, wait, just reread your comment. If `$(document).ready` isn't firing, that's a different issue.